# Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 infinite login redirect with 2 step authentication

Tags: google-account, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7, 2-step-verification

I've just bought a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 and tried to login with my google (gmail) account (which has 2 step authentication) and it redirected me to the web login which I completed (with the text message for the code because it's an unrecognized device). It then returns me to the OS login which I try again which then redirects me back to the web login.

So I get stuck in this infinite loop when trying to login. I assume that this is because I've got 2 step authentication enabled. Any idea how to login in the Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 with 2 step authentication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to set up an "application specific" password for your tab, and enter THAT password when you enter your account details.
Now you totally avoid the second screen asking for the code.
You can create an application specific password at 
https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens (at least that's the one I use)

Kind regards

joern

Comment: He already has it.

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily turn off 2-step verification, and turn it back on after you have logged in.

I had the same issue with Galaxy Tab 2, and did just that.